# How to remove the slug of a theme in wordpress URL

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

[image]

Here is the url in browser i want to change tu.edu.pk/#kingster-moblie-menu to tu.edu.pk/#tu-moblie-menu

Please Hepl me out how to reslove this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this js on your js file

```
// Replaces the location of the current window with the new one.
window.location.replace("https://www.tu.edu.pk/#tu-moblie-menu");
```